# AngularJS $http POST request different results with then and success

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Something is driving me nuts; maybe someone can help me out with the following? :

I am using **AngularJS 1.2.26** (have to because IE8 needs to be supported)

I have to invoke some backend services that were initially build for a backbone frontend. I managed to do that in the following way:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  transformRequest: this._transformRequest,
  data: formData
})
.success(function (data) {
  // bla bla not relevant
}).error(function (error) {
  // bla bla not relevant
});
```

Now i try to work with the then function as i find that more consequent, so i change the code into:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  transformRequest: this._transformRequest,
  data: formData
}).then(
  function (response) {
    // not relevant
  }, function (error) {
    // not relevant
  });
```

According to me, in theory this should have the same result as the initial implementation, however to my surprise the request now fails on the server. While debugging I noticed that the result of the transform request function delivers a very different result in both scenario's in the request that is handled with success and error the result of transform request is as follows:

> com.bank.token.session=XXXXX&model=%7B%22relatieRol%22%3A%22AANVRAGER%22%2C%22evaUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%2C%22sfhUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%2C%22bkrUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%2C%22bkrBekendCd%22%3A%22GOED_BEKEND%22%7D

When i use the 'then' function as the way to handle the result the transformRequest function returns the following (wrong) result:

> com.bank.token.session=XXXXXXXXXXX&model=%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22relatieRol%22%3A%22AANVRAGER%22%2C%22evaUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%2C%22sfhUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%2C%22bkrUitgevoerdDat%22%3Anull%7D%2C%22status%22%3A200%2C%22config%22%3A%7B%22method%22%3A%22POST%22%2C%22transformResponse%22%3A%5Bnull%5D%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Femployee%2Findex.html%2Ffoo-web%2Fxchannel-foo-secure-portlet%2F1598792178%2Fver%3D2.0%2Fresource%2Fid%3Dfoo-fetch-%2Frparam%3Dportal%3DfooPortal.wsp%22%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22Content-Type%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22%2C%22Accept%22%3A%22application%2Fjson%2C%20text%2Fplain%2C%20*%2F*%22%7D%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22com.bank.token.session%22%3A%22XXXXXXXXXX%22%2C%22model%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22relatieRol%5C%22%3A%5C%22AANVRAGER%5C%22%7D%22%7D%7D%2C%22statusText%22%3A%22OK%22%2C%22bkrBekendCd%22%3A%22GOED_BEKEND%22%7D

This really surprises me; how can the handler on the $http service influence the way the request is handled? I would like to use 'then' for handling my $http POST; but it seems not to work. Anybody knows why? Many thanks in advance!

my transformRequest function looks like this:

```
        _transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
            }

            console.log('transform: ', str.join("&"));
            return str.join("&");
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

`success` and `error` *unpack* the `data` property of the response for you (as well as route to the pretty names).  So, if you change to `then` you need to manually address the `data` property of the response in order to get the same information:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  transformRequest: this._transformRequest,
  data: formData
}).then(
  function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    // not relevant
  }, function (error) {
    var data = error.data;
    // not relevant
  });
```

Here is the relevant part in the [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http
>   specific methods: success and error. The then method takes two
>   arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a
>   response object. The success and error methods take a single argument
>   - a function that will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. The arguments passed into these functions are
>   destructured representation of the response object passed into the
>   then method. The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} - Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. However this is **not the answer to my question**. My question is about the different results I get in my **transformRequest function** (the data that is transmitted to the server). My problem is that I do not understand **why transformRequest** gives me **different** results for handling with **'then'** vs handling with **'success/error'**

Comment: +1. Excellent explanation. @timboektoe I don't know exactly what type of answer you are looking for, but this clearly answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: They do both in the question and in answer.