# res.send sending whole object as a response instead of the content

Tags: node.js, request, response, aws-lambda, facebook-chatbot

```
  'use strict'
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var request = require('request');
    var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware');
    var app = express();
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    var VALIDATION_TOKEN = 'Serverless_My_Token';
    app.set('port', (port));
// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());
    // Process application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
// for Facebook verification
        app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.rawHeaders[1]);
            if (jsonObject.params.querystring['hub.verify_token'] === 'serverless_my_token') {
         var hubChallenge = jsonObject.params.querystring['hub.challenge'];

         return res.send(hubChallenge);
    }
    res.send('Error, wrong token')
        });
```

When calling the get API res.send is sending whole response object,

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "",
  "headers": {
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

I need to send only hubChallenge variable as a response:

hub.challenge number: example: 245421998as a response.

How can I make only hubchallenge variable return as response instead of whole object containing status. etc..

Error:

```
The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="245421998", received="{\"statusCode\":200,..."
```

Comment: Are you using angular $http from client side? In that case [this answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27906815/6248016)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add this somewhere after `app = express();` to your code:

```
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());
```

Right now it seams that you import `awsServerlessExpressMiddleware` but you're not using it in your app anywhere.

Comment: I have it in my code didnt update in example. Add in the question